# Working with hierarchical data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

If I have hierarchical data in a Google Sheet as in columns A and B in the example below, how can I write a formula that will fill the corresponding cells in column C with the product of the "parent" value in A1, and the "child" values in column B. That is, The formula in C8 for example, will search upward in column A until it finds the value 5 in A6, then multiplies it by 8, the value in B8.

[image: Example Sheet]

Obviously I'm trying to avoid having to put the "parent" value in every row in column A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fiddling around and jogging my memory on ArrayFormulas I figured out how to get the result I wanted. Here's the formula I'm using:

```
=ArrayFormula(index($B$2:$B2,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER($B$2:$B2),ROW($B$2:$B2)))-1,1))
```

(Note: Row 1 contains headings)

Edit: Explanation of how I arrived at this solution:

Ordinarily, IF(ISNUMBER(cell)), and ROW(cell) would return TRUE/FALSE, or a row number respectively. When used in an array formula and a range of cells as input instead, what you get is a list of TRUE/FALSE values, and row numbers evaluated for each cell in the input range. Wrap MAX around that and it will return the position in those two lists where IF(ISNUMBER()) is TRUE and the row number returned by ROW() is the highest, effectively searching from the bottom of the range.

The absolute reference for the first element in the range to be searched (in this case $B$2) keeps the range anchored to the same starting location when dragging the formula into other cells, while the lower bound of the range (in this case $B2) to be searched grows vertically.

Finally, the INDEX takes the input range, row number returned by the above (-1 row because of the header) and column position (1, since there is only one column) in order to return the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this would be to associate each value in column B with a category or key that can be used to lookup the value for A in a separate table. This abstracts it somewhat, so you can change the values for the A column without having to have them in every row, but there's no empty cells.

i.e.

[image: screenshot]

and lookup table:

[image: screenshot]

In column C

```
= VLOOKUP($A1, <range for category lookup table>, 2, 0) * $B1
```

(And then this formula can be filled down)

[More on VLOOKUP in Google Sheets here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

Alternatively I suppose you could use a formula to find the last non-empty row in column A, or something along those lines, but this is more of a hack than a proper way to structure your data. Tables aren't really designed to be used in a hierarchical fashion like what you've shown. But they can easily represent hierarchical data using techniques like what I've suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I overlooked that. My data already has such categories as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, I guess I jumped the gun a little. Part one of your solution isn't working for me 100%. Because of the way the data is laid out and the way "categories" are associated with data, it doesn't produce consistent results when I expand the formula over the full range (remembering to use absolute references of course).

Comment: VLOOKUP doesn't work because it searches down from the top of a range and seems to need a specific search-key to work (the wildcard "*" is not working to return true when it finds -any- numeric value). I remember doing something like this in Excel a while back using array formulas but I can't remember how. Serves me right for taking a year long sabbatical :P If I don't get any other responses by the morning I'll mark yours as accepted and move on with my life. Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you need a wildcard? Anyway, if no match is found `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A`

Comment: I would have needed a wildcard because the thing I'm searching for isn't a constant. I needed a way to get the VLOOKUP looking for anything that is a number (or even just anything that isn't a blank cell), and I thought using a wildcard might satisfy that, which it didn't. I did get this working using array formulas in order to effectively do a search from the bottom of a range to the top. I've posted the explanation in the comments above now.